# I can't insert article with character and programing language script into databse

Tags: php

I have project of create something like blog.  The problem am facing now.

1. trying to post articles within there are php, html code and contain some character keep failed.
2. later on  it try to use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['body'])`. it change but in frontend
   the results is
   `dont ' me i s't (opsdd) &lt;====&gt; saya whatis ? ! ---`

My code:

```
session_start();
include('../../conn/connect.php');
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $for_query = '';
    if (!empty($_POST["sub"])) {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $body = htmlspecialchars($_POST['body']);
        $menu = $_POST['menu'];

        foreach ($_POST["sub"] as $language) {
            $for_query .= $language . ',';
        }

        $year = date("Y");
        foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
            $file = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $extension = explode('.', $name);
            $extension = end($extension);
            $extension = strtolower($extension);
            $random_name = rand();

            $images = $subject . "." . $extension;
            $save =  $_SESSION['folder'] . '/' . $images;

            $url = $images;
            if (
                $_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 &&
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "../users/{$_SESSION['folder']}/{$images}")
            ) {
                $uploaded[]=$images;

                $for_query = substr($for_query, 0, -2);
                $query = "INSERT INTO content (subject,body,menu,sub,files) VALUES ('$subject','$body','$menu','$for_query','$save')";
                $q = $db->prepare($query);
                $q->execute();
            } else {
            echo "<label class='text-danger'>* Please Select Atleast one</label>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using PDO or mysqli, but using prepared statements will fix your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/909973

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967233/how-to-insert-string-with-single-quote-symbol shows you how to stop problems with quotes, BUT the duplicate (as already indicated) is a much better solution.